# functions as objects and function calls

Tags: javascript, function

I'm reading this - http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/ but there is an example I don't quite understand.

```
// A function being attached to an object at runtime.
var myName = "the global object";
var sayHello = function() {
    console.log( "Hi! My name is " + this.myName );
};
var myObject = {
    myName: "Rebecca"
};
var secondObject = {
    myName: "Colin"
};

myObject.sayHello = sayHello;
secondObject.sayHello = sayHello;

sayHello();              // "Hi! My name is the global object"
myObject.sayHello();     // "Hi! My name is Rebecca"
secondObject.sayHello(); // "Hi! My name is Colin"
```

I understand it all, except this two lines:

```
myObject.sayHello = sayHello;
secondObject.sayHello = sayHello;
```

What exactly do we do with them? We create new keys to the objects and state that their values will be the function sayHello, but we omit the parenthesis in order not to explicitly   call the function? And why do we need them? If we omit them, won't we get the same result and won't it be again "a function being attached to an object at runtime"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We create new keys to the objects and state that their values will be the function sayHello,

Yes

> but we omit the parenthesis in order not to explicitly call the function?

Yes. If you called the function then you would assign the return value of the function call instead of the function itself.

> If we omit them, won't we get the same result

If you omit those two lines, then `myObject.sayHello` will be `undefined` and you will get an error when you try to call `undefined()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! So we can't call a function to an object if we don't previously add a new key with this function to the object?

Comment: `call`, `apply` and `bind` provide ways to call a function in the context of an object without fire making it a method on the object, but to call one as a method it must be the value of a property on the object.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sayHello = function() {
    ...
};
myObject.sayHello = sayHello;
```

is the same as:

```
var myObject = {
    myName: "Rebecca",
    sayHello: function() {
        ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that you point `myObject.sayHello` to the `sayHello` function (and you omit the parenthesis, otherwise you would assign the *result* of the called function). Whenever you call the `sayHello` function, the `this` will be the object of which you call `sayHello`.

So for `myObject.sayHello`, the `this` will be `myObject`.

For simply calling `sayHello`, what you actually do is calling `window.sayHello`, so `this` is set to `window`.